# np.isreal behavior different in pandas.DataFrame and numpy.array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a `array` like below

```
np.array(["hello","world",{"a":5,"b":6,"c":8},"usa","india",{"d":9,"e":10,"f":11}])
```

and a `pandas` `DataFrame` like below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ["hello","world",{"a":5,"b":6,"c":8},"usa","india",{"d":9,"e":10,"f":11}]})
```

When I apply `np.isreal` to `DataFrame`

```
df.applymap(np.isreal)
Out[811]: 
       A
0  False
1  False
2   True
3  False
4  False
5   True
```

When I do `np.isreal` for the `numpy` array.

```
np.isreal( np.array(["hello","world",{"a":5,"b":6,"c":8},"usa","india",{"d":9,"e":10,"f":11}]))
Out[813]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

I must using the `np.isreal` in the wrong use case, But can you help me about ***why the result is different*** ?

Comment: This is even more confusing to me than the answer you gave to trigger this question! :). Not only why is it different, but why does it differentiate between strings and dicts in `pandas`?

Comment: @roganjosh I just have time to test it , even we use it in the wrong way, we are expected the same wrong answer , but this one ..LOL

Comment: Pandas is a bit of a red herring here, that just uses the element-wise behavior e.g. `[np.isreal(aa) for aa in np.array(["hello","world",{"a":5,"b":6,"c":8},"usa","india",{"d":9,"e":10,"f":11}])]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A partial answer is that [`isreal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isreal.html) is only intended to be used on array-like as the first argument.

You want to use [`isrealobj`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.isrealobj.html) on each element to get the bahavior you see here:

```
In [11]: a = np.array(["hello","world",{"a":5,"b":6,"c":8},"usa","india",{"d":9,"e":10,"f":11}])

In [12]: a
Out[12]:
array(['hello', 'world', {'a': 5, 'b': 6, 'c': 8}, 'usa', 'india',
       {'d': 9, 'e': 10, 'f': 11}], dtype=object)

In [13]: [np.isrealobj(aa) for aa in a]
Out[13]: [True, True, True, True, True, True]

In [14]: np.isreal(a)
Out[14]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

That does leave the question, what does `np.isreal` do on something that isn't array-like e.g.

```
In [21]: np.isrealobj("")
Out[21]: True

In [22]: np.isreal("")
Out[22]: False

In [23]: np.isrealobj({})
Out[23]: True

In [24]: np.isreal({})
Out[24]: True
```

---

It turns out this stems from `.imag` since the [test that `isreal` does](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.0/numpy/lib/type_check.py#L221-L249) is:

```
return imag(x) == 0   # note imag == np.imag
```

and that's it.

```
In [31]: np.imag(a)
Out[31]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=object)

In [32]: np.imag("")
Out[32]:
array('',
      dtype='<U1')

In [33]: np.imag({})
Out[33]: array(0, dtype=object)
```

This looks up the `.imag` attribute on the array.

```
In [34]: np.asanyarray("").imag
Out[34]:
array('',
      dtype='<U1')

In [35]: np.asanyarray({}).imag
Out[35]: array(0, dtype=object)
```

I'm not sure why this isn't set in the string case yet...

Comment: This doesn't fully answer the question of what isreal is doing here, but the docs make it clear the first argument should be array-like (so I think all bets are off ..) and we have to look at the code

Comment: Thank you , Make me aware not all `numpy` function can be borrowed without think to  pandas calculation

Comment: @Wen it tuns out it comes from interesting behavior of `.imag` https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.0/numpy/lib/type_check.py#L221-L249

Comment: I found it .. just not sure about `.imag`

Comment: @Wen Ah, that actually makes a *little* more sense than my theory, but it's still definitely peculiar.  I had assumed that `isreal` was a ufunc but clearly it is not.

Comment: @Iguananaut I think the imag property is set somewhere in C code (in constructor of array object)...

Comment: @Wen will update if I find the where imag is set in the C constructor. :)

Comment: @AndyHayden this is so interesting , you bring me do deep in it . :-) Appreciated your help

Answer (score 4):

I think this a small bug in Numpy to be honest.  Here Pandas is just looping over each item in the column and calling `np.isreal()` on it.  E.g.:

```
>>> np.isreal("a")
False
>>> np.isreal({})
True
```

I think the paradox here has to do with how `np.real()` treats inputs of `dtype=object`.  My guess is it's taking the object pointer and treating it like an int, so of course `np.isreal(<some object>)` returns True.  Over an array of mixed types like `np.array(["A", {}])`, the array is of `dtype=object` so `np.isreal()` is treating all the elements (including the strings) the way it would anything with `dtype=object`.

To be clear, I think the bug is in how `np.isreal()` treats arbitrary objects in a `dtype=object` array, but I haven't confirmed this explicitly.

Comment: we were both very fast, you just beat me :)

Comment: It's a strange question but definitely an interesting one?

Comment: speaking of strangeness of the question: what is the purpose of the OP here? Why is @wen trying to use isreal on these strings and dictionaries, that are not even numbers. The purpose of a isreal is to know if something is complex or not according to numpy documentation.

Comment: @Semihcan I raised it as a comment to an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46856468/4799172) because I couldn't understand why `isreal` could be used for differentiating between dicts and strings.

Comment: @Semihcan sorry, I originally gave the wrong link. Fixed that in my last comment. I'm also curious of the origin of this as a filter on dataframe columns for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you , You answer is making a lot of sense too

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple things going on here. First is pointed out by the previous answers in that `np.isreal` acts strangely when passed ojbects. 
 However, I think you are also confused about what [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) is doing. [Difference between map, applymap and apply methods in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19798153/difference-between-map-applymap-and-apply-methods-in-pandas) is always a great reference.

In this case what you think you are doing is actually:

```
df.apply(np.isreal, axis=1)
```

Which essentially calls np.isreal(df), whereas df.applymap(np.isreal) is essentially calling np.isreal on each individual element of df. e.g

```
np.isreal(df.A)

array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

np.array([np.isreal(x) for x in df.A])

array([False, False,  True, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Related to this earlier comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46856988/np-isreal-behavior-different-in-pandas-dataframe-and-numpy-array/46857114#comment80661655_46856988