# What does the function np.isreal does in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Can anyone explain the below code?

```
pima_df[~pima_df.applymap(np.isreal).all(1)]
```

`pima_df` is a dataframe.

Comment: You might want to look at this for some more information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46856988/np-isreal-behavior-different-in-pandas-dataframe-and-numpy-array

Answer (score 1):

You are extracting rows in which atleast one complex number occurs.

e.g : pima_df =

```
    a   b
0   1   2
1   2   4+3j
2   3   5
```

result would be :

```
    a   b
1   2   (4+3j)
```

in short :

`applymap` - apply function on each and every element of dataframe.

`np.isreal` - returns true for real otherwise false

`all` - returns true if each element along an axis is true otherwise false.

`~` - negates the boolean index

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the doc or help(np.isreal).

```
Returns a bool array, where True if input element is real.

If element has complex type with zero complex part, the return value
for that element is True.
```

To be precise Numpy Provides a set of methods for comparing and performing operations on arrays elementwise:

```
np.isreal : Determines whether each element of array is real.
np.all :    Determines whether all array element of a specific array evaluate to True.
tilde(~) :  used for Boolean indexing which means not.
applymap:   applymap works element-wise on a DataFrame.
all()   :   used to find rows where all the values are True.
```

The ~ is the operator equivalent of the **invert** dunder which has been overridden explicitly for the purpose performing vectorized logical inversions on pd.DataFrame/pd.Series objects.

> Example of boolean index (~):

```
>>> df 
    a  b  c  d
0   a  a  2  6
1   a  a  4  7
2   b  a  1  6
3   b  a  2  1
4   c  b  3  6
5   c  b  0  2
6   d  b  3  3
7   d  b  2  1
8   e  c  4  3
9   e  c  2  0
10  f  c  0  6
11  f  c  1  2

>>> df.query('a in b')
   a  b  c  d
0  a  a  2  6
1  a  a  4  7
2  b  a  1  6
3  b  a  2  1
4  c  b  3  6
5  c  b  0  2
```

**OR**

```
>>> df[~df.a.isin(df.b)]    # same as above
    a  b  c  d
6   d  b  3  3
7   d  b  2  1
8   e  c  4  3
9   e  c  2  0
10  f  c  0  6
11  f  c  1  2
```

hope this will help.