# Pandas Dataframe Turned my Dictionaries into String

Tags: python, string, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dataframe, each cell saves a dictionary. Before exporting the dataframe, I could call each cell as an individual dataframe.

However, after saving the dataframe as csv and reopening this each cell became string so I could not turn the cell I called into a dataframe anymore.

[The output should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLQRr.png)

[After saving the dataframe as csv, dictionary became string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YX0CK.png)

I was surprising to learn after my research on Stackoverflow, there were not many people experienced same issue as I'm having. I wondered whether my practice is wrong. I only found two posts related to my issue. Here is the one ([dict objects converting to string when read from csv to dataframe pandas python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46858848/dict-objects-converting-to-string-when-read-from-csv-to-dataframe-pandas-python)).

I basically tried json, ast.literal_eval and yaml but none of these could solve my issue.

This is the first part of my code(I created this four list to store my data which I called from an api)

```
tickers4 = []
last_1st_bs4 = []
last_2nd_bs4 = []
last_3rd_bs4 = []

for i in range(len(tickers)):
    try:
        ticker = tickers.loc[i, 'ticker']
        ann_yr = 2018

        yr_1st = intrinio.financials_period(ticker, str(ann_yr-1), fiscal_period='FY', statement='balance_sheet')
        yr_2nd = intrinio.financials_period(ticker, str(ann_yr-2), fiscal_period='FY', statement='balance_sheet')
        yr_3rd = intrinio.financials_period(ticker, str(ann_yr-3), fiscal_period='FY', statement='balance_sheet')

        tickers4.append(ticker)
        last_1st_bs4.append(yr_1st)
        last_2nd_bs4.append(yr_2nd)
        last_3rd_bs4.append(yr_3rd)

        print('{} Feeding data {}'.format(i, ticker))

    except:
        tickers4.append(ticker)
        last_1st_bs4.append(0)
        last_2nd_bs4.append(0)
        last_3rd_bs4.append(0)
        print('{} Error {}'.format(i, ticker))
```

Second part: I put them into a dataframe and saved as csv

```
BS = pd.DataFrame()
BS['ticker'] = tickers4
BS['BS_2017'] = last_1st_bs4
BS['BS_2016'] = last_2nd_bs4
BS['BS_2015'] = last_3rd_bs4
BS.to_csv('Balance_Sheet_2015_2017.csv')
```

now, I need read this csv in another notebook

```
BS = pd.read_csv('./Balance_Sheet_2015_2017.csv', index_col=0)
BS.loc[9, 'BS_2017']
```

here is the result I got:
`'      cashandequivalents  shortterminvestments  notereceivable  \\\nyear                                                             \n2017        2.028900e+10          5.389200e+10    1.779900e+10   \n\n      accountsreceivable  netinventory  othercurrentassets  \\\nyear                                                         \n2017        1.787400e+10  4.855000e+09        1.393600e+10   \n\n      totalcurrentassets        netppe  longterminvestments  \\\nyear                                                          \n2017        1.286450e+11  3.378300e+10         1.947140e+11   \n\n      othernoncurrentassets            ...              \\\nyear                                   ...               \n2017           1.817700e+10            ...               \n\n      commitmentsandcontingencies  commonequity  retainedearnings  \\\nyear                                                                \n2017                          0.0  3.586700e+10      9.833000e+10   \n\n             aoci  totalcommonequity   totalequity  \\\nyear                                                 \n2017 -150000000.0       1.340470e+11  1.340470e+11   \n\n      totalequityandnoncontrollinginterests  totalliabilitiesandequity  \\\nyear                                                                     \n2017                           1.340470e+11               3.753190e+11   \n\n      currentdeferredrevenue  noncurrentdeferredrevenue  \nyear                                                     \n2017            7.548000e+09               2.836000e+09  \n\n[1 rows x 30 columns]'`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Put your code snd output here instead of link.

Comment: I wonder that if you want export it into a file and load it next time into python? Or you just want to export it into a file and load it with some graphic software?

Answer (score 2):

CSV is not an appropriate format for saving dictionaries (and honestly, putting dictionaries into DataFrames isn't a great data structure). You should try writing the DataFrame to json instead: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Comment: Thanks for providing alternative methods. Do you know if there is anyway I can convert strings back to dictionaries? it took me days to collect those data.

Comment: @JonZhao you can use json library  d = json.loads(j), it will convert your string to dictionary again

Comment: @NagaKiran I tried  json, ast.literal_eval and yaml. however, json and eval throw a indent error. yaml still returns a string but better format.

Comment: I should know this earlier. pickle save the dataframe with original format but csv saves your dataframe into comma separated list!. I wish I read this earlier. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48770542/what-is-the-difference-between-save-a-pandas-dataframe-to-pickle-and-to-csv

Answer (score 2):

I had this same error once.  I solved it by using `DataFrame.to_pickle()` instead of `DataFrame.to_csv()`.

Everything in a CSV file is plain text, even the numerical values.  When you load a CSV file into a spreadsheet program, there are parsers which look for strings which are recognizable as numbers, or dates, and convert them accordingly.

A CSV file can't easily hold the more complex Python objects, but Pandas won't throw an error if you place Python objects in a DataFrame.  It converts them to their string representations.

Comment: Hi John, I guess that would work before I saved my dataframe, but my original data format is already changed and I'm trying to convert that back to dictionaries. Thanks for your solution, I'll use in the future.